# How do I float the OK button in a Dojo MessageBox to the right?

Tags: dojo

How do I float the OK button in a Dojo MessageBox to the right?

```
new MessageBox({
    title: "Validation Error",
    content: dspContent,
    messageType: MessageBox.messageTypes.MESSAGE_TYPE_OK
}).show();
```

Comment: What is `MessageBox`? AFAIK no such thing exists by that name in dijit or dojox.

Comment: Sorry, its actually extended from Dialog.